# Conforming variant of the old "struct hack" (?)

Tags: c, c89

I believe I've found a way to achieve something like the well-known "struct hack" in portable C89. I'm curious if this really strictly conforms to C89.

The main idea is: I allocate memory large enough to hold an initial struct and the elements of the array. The exact size is `(K + N) * sizeof(array_base_type)`, where `K` is chosen so that `K * sizeof(array_base_type) >= sizeof(the_struct)` and `N` is the number of array elements.

First, I dereference the pointer that `malloc()` returned to store `the_struct`, then I use pointer arithmetic to obtain a pointer to the beginning of the array following the struct.

One line of code is worth more than a thousand words, so here is a minimal implementation:

```
typedef struct Header {
    size_t length;
    /* other members follow */
} Header;

typedef struct Value {
    int type;
    union {
        int intval;
        double fltval;
    } v;
} Value;

/* round up to nearest multiple of sizeof(Value) so that a Header struct fits in */
size_t n_hdr = (sizeof(Header) + sizeof(Value) - 1) / sizeof(Value);

size_t n_arr = 42; /* arbitrary array size here */
void *frame = malloc((n_hdr + n_arr) * sizeof(Value));

if (!frame)
    return NULL;

Header *hdr = frame;
Value *stack_bottom = (Value *)frame + n_hdr;
```

My main concern is that the last two assignments (using `frame` as both a pointer to Header and a pointer to Value) may violate the strict aliasing rule. I do not, however, dereference `hdr` as a pointer to Value - it's only pointer arithmetic that is performed on `frame` in order to access the first element of the value array, so I don't effectively access *the same* object using pointers of different types.

So, is this approach any better than the classic struct hack (which has been officially deemed UB), or is it UB too?

Comment: I don't know about the conformance of this solution, but it's not really new to me. ;)

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar It may not be new :) It's not that advanced or anything... and I don't care either, I just need to get this work. I needed something like flexible struct members (from C99) in C89 but the struct hack is non-conformant. So I thought about it a bit and all I could come up with was this.

Comment: There is a good discussion of strict aliasing at http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html . Basically, the compiler has to be sure that modifying 'stack_bottom' will not also modify 'frame' (and vice-versa). You should be able to do this with "(Value *) ((char *) frame + n_hdr)".

Comment: @mkfs That's a very useful link, thanks! As to the code, did you mean `(Value *)((char *)frame + n_hdr * sizeof(Value))`?

Comment: @mkfs Furthermore, is it indeed "modifying `stack_bottom`" or "modifying the object pointed to by `stack_bottom`"? (The point is, the same objects are not pointed to by different pointers, only different ones.)

Comment: Ah yes, there should be a "n_hdr * sizeof(Value)" in there -- I did not entirely grasp what the initialization of stack_bottom was doing, at first. As for the compiler, yes it is concerned with modifications to the object pointed to by stack_bottom -- the actual location to which the type "Value" is applied.

Comment: @mkfs After all, I'll just go with a `union { Header hdr; Value val; }` and a pointer to it will be the stack pointer. The first element is the frame header, the remaining ones are the values.

Comment: That should work nicely. And somehow, it feels like cheating ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "obvious" (well... not exactly obvious, but it's what comes to *my* mind anyway :-) ) way to cause this to break is to use a vectorizing compiler that somehow decides it's OK to load, say, 64 `Header`s into a vector register from the 42-rounded-up-to-64+ area at `hdr` which comes from `malloc` which always allocates enough to vectorize.  Storing the vector register back to memory might overwrite one of the `Value`s.

I think this vectorizing compiler could point to the standard (well, if a compiler has fingers...) and claim conformance.

In practice, though, I'd expect this code to work.  If you come across a vectorizing compiler, add even more space (do the rounding up with a machine-dependent macro that can insert a minimum) and charge on. :-)

Comment: This is a nice example (+1). One more thing, wouldn't this cause @mkfs's suggestion (aliasing through a character type) to break as well? Also, could it be possible to prevent such a vectorizing compiler from vectorizing the hell out of my brain by aliasing `hdr` using a pointer to array of 1 (one) `Header` (i. e. `Header (*)[1]`) or something similar?

Comment: I don't know for sure, I've never actually worked with vectorizing C compilers.  I believe they exist for some Cray and Convex systems but don't know how they choose when to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm waiting for mkfs's response before accepting your answer. The explanation is appreciated. I think I'll go with my original solution or with the `char *` aliasing one, and I will try very hard to test my code using various compilers, at multiple optimization levels, trying out combinations of the `-fstrict-aliasing` and `-ftree-vectorize` flags. Also, a big red splash image in the README and a reference to it in the comments will be added, so that users of my library know that *my* code is broken, not theirs. Thanks once again.