# Difference between use of pointer and array with zero elements in structs

Tags: c, struct, coding-style

How do the two implementations differ:

```
struct queue {
    int a;
    int b;
    q_info *array;
};
```

and

```
struct queue {
    int a;
    int b;
    q_info array[0];
};
```

Comment: what clever thing do you want to do with `q_info array[0];`  ?

Comment: They differ in that `T array[0]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Worth noting that [0] is non-standard (although supported by gcc and msvc). As i recall, C99 allowed usage of `some_type some_array[];` for the same purpose. Before this, it was usually achieved by using [1], and manipulating with `sizeof` later.

Comment: @H2CO3 standard explicitly allows only greater-than-zero (6.7.5.2), so it isn't. If compiler supports this - it's an extension and still well-defined.

Comment: @keltar Indeed, 6.7.5.2:1 is in a “Constraints” section, so a standard-conforming compiler is required to issue a diagnostic, but what happens after that is undefined behavior (and, by the way, GCC does not issue a diagnostic).

Comment: @PascalCuoq because zero-sized arrays is GNU C extension. Try it with -std=c99 -pedantic

Comment: @keltar At least [0] clearly indicates that some magic is expected. The standard-compliant declaration [1] where a flexible array member is intended is usually followed by undefined behavior later in the use of the struct: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/31/From-Pascal-strings-to-Python-tuples

Comment: @PascalCuoq so please give a better solution. Espetially for msvc, which still have no support for C99. This came out of necessity. [0] or [] changes sizeof, it's hard to implement as macro.

Comment: @keltar I do not know of any solution that preserves compatibility with both a hypothetical modern compiler that would aggressively optimize anything undefined and with MSVC. Fortunately modern compilers aren't very good at UB-based optimizations yet, but their makers have repeatedly made their intentions clear in the last decade.

Comment: @keltar [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310789/conforming-variant-of-the-old-struct-hack). I ended up creating an array of unions.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I recommend [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310789/conforming-variant-of-the-old-struct-hack) to you too.

Comment: @H2CO3 Regarding the tangential discussion below a deleted answer there, C99 7.20.3:1 says “The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object” about allocation functions including `malloc()`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Yes, I then realized, thanks. (So I don't think that the deleted answer was correct -- still not sure about the conformance of the mutated struct hack, though.)

Comment: @H2CO3 out of curiosity - have you ever found a combination of compiler/flags that breaks 'classic' approach? If not - it's hardly any better.

Comment: @keltar No, I haven't, but I'd rather not rely on "but it will work anyway" (especially since I used that in a - say "infrastructure" - project that should be highly portable and reliable). In fact, I'd be happy to see the struct hack being broken with some compiler.

Comment: @H2CO3 maybe i haven't got answer in your link right, but doesn't it says it isn't guaranteed either? So how is it better, aside from reduced readability and forced manual initialisation? But anyway, my point is that e.g. by standard nullpointer isn't required to be all-0-bits, so memset(&somestruct, 0, sizeof(somestruct)) theoretically may be wrong if struct have pointers. But in this case, non-guaranteed memset is better for performance, readability, ease-of-use and maintainability reasons. I feel the same way for flexible array members - in theory they could be broken, but they won't.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I've often thought that zero-sized arrays should have been allowed by the standard, so long as code doesn't access unallocated space. Given `struct S {int a[CONST_EXPR];} s,*p; int i;` a compiler would, if `CONST_EXPR==1`, be entitled to replace `s.a[i];` with `s[0]`. To ensure compatibility with a huge amount of existing code, it would be necessary to forbid such optimization when accessing `p->a[i]` (though I don't think the standard does), but if the standard had always allowed zero-sized arrays it could have said that *only* zero-sized arrays may be accessed beyond their size.

Answer (score 11):

The second `struct` does not use an array of zero elements - this is a pre-C99 trick for making flexible array members. The difference is that in the first snippet you need two `malloc`s - one for the `struct`, and one for the `array`, while in the second one you can do both in a single `malloc`:

```
size_t num_entries = 100;
struct queue *myQueue = malloc(sizeof(struct queue)+sizeof(q_info)*num_entries);
```

instead of

```
size_t num_entries = 100;
struct queue *myQueue = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
myQueue->array = malloc(sizeof(q_info)*num_entries);
```

This lets you save on the number of deallocations, provides better locality of references, and also saves the space for one pointer.

Starting with C99 you can drop zero from the declaration of the array member:

```
struct queue {
    int a;
    int b;
    q_info array[];
};
```

Comment: The zero-sized array member was (unfortunately IMHO) never allowed by standard C; prior to C99 if one wanted to avoid Undefined Behavior it was necessary to use an array of size MAX_QUEUE_SIZE and allocate sizeof(queue)-sizeof(elementType)*(MAX_QUEUE_SIZE-num_entries) bytes.  A lot of code has been written which uses a size of one and allocates sizeof(queue)+sizeof(elementType)*(num_entries-1) bytes, but that will sometimes allocate more space than needed, and is Undefined Behavior (though fortunately compilers will generally cause it to behave as intended).

Answer (score 2):

These are completely different things:

- The first contains a pointer to an *external* array.
- the second is an *inline* array that happens to have zero elements.

The reason people do this is it's more space-efficient. You simply over-allocate the memory the struct needs, and then pretend the array has more elements then declared - the compiler won't mind (usually).

It also means you have one less pointer to dereference through, and you can allocate and free the memory for the struct and the array all in one.

Obviously, this trick only works when the array is the *last* element in the struct.

Answer (score 1):

In the first one there is actually a pointer allocated in `struct queue`, and `sizeof(struct queue) == 2 * sizeof(int) + sizeof(q_info*)`

In the second one there is no pointer or anything named `array` really exists in `struct queue`, and `sizeof(struct queue) == 2 * sizeof(int)`. This is known as a trick to conveniently reference the data before or later using `array`. I've used this trick in implementing a memory allocator.

Answer (score 1):

For the zero-sized array member, you can, when you allocate the structure, allocate more memory than the size of `struct queue` (for example `malloc(sizeof(struct queue) + sizeof(q_info) * 10)`) to have a contiguous area of memory you can use. Then the array will be part of that memory allocated, and for the example allocation you have ten `q_info` entries in it.

For the pointer, you have to make two allocations, one for the `queue` structure, and one for the `array` member. You of course have to call `free` twice, once for the `array` pointer and once for the structure.

However, once allocated *both* can be used the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
q_info array[0];
```

decays to a pointer because of the automatic conversion. However, it is not assignable. You cannot say

```
array = <some address of an object>;
```

afterwards.