# Accessing the -1 element of an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, struct

I have an array of structs, which is dynamically allocated. A pointer to this array is passed around to other functions.

```
struct body{
    char* name; 
    double mass; 
    // ... some more stuff
    };

 body *bodies = malloc(Number_of_bodies*sizeof(body));
```

I need to know the size of the array, so I'm storing the size in one of the structs, which is in the 0th element of the array (the first struct).

```
bodies[0].mass = (double)Number_of_bodies;
```

I then return from the function a pointer to the 1st element of the array i.e `bodies[1]`

```
  return (bodies+1);
```

Now, when I use this pointer in other functions, the data should start at the 0th element.

```
  body *new_bodies = (bodies+1);     //Just trying to show what happens effectively when i pass to another function
  new_bodies[0] = *(bodies+1);       //I Think
```

If I want to see the initial struct, which was at `bodies[0]`, does that mean in other functions I have to access `new_bodies[-1]` ?

Is this something I can do? 
How can I access the initial struct?

Comment: Yes. Sure. Why not? `a[b]` is defined as `*(a+b)`.

Comment: Closely related to [Negative array indexes in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3473675/1708801)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use `new_bodies[-1]` to access the initial element of the array. This is perfectly legal.

The reason behind this is pointer arithmetic: square brackets is another way of writing `+`, so when you write `new_bodies[-1]` it is the same as `*(new_bodies-1)`.

Since `new_bodies` has been obtained as `bodies+1`, `new_bodies-1` is `(bodies+1)-1`, or `bodies`, making `new_bodies[-1]` identical to `bodies[0]`.

**Note**: It looks like you are trying to shoehorn the number of elements into the initial element of the array of your `struct`s, re-purposing the `mass` field for it. This will work, but it is suboptimal, both in terms of memory allocation (a pointer `name` remains unused) but most importantly in terms of readability. You would be a lot better off using a flexible array member in a `struct` that stores the number of entries explicitly:

```
struct body {
    char* name; 
    double mass; 
    // ... some more stuff
};
struct bodies {
    size_t count;
    body bodies[]; // <<== Flexible array member
};
...
bodies *bb = malloc(sizeof(bodies)+Number_of_bodies*sizeof(body));
bb->count = Number_of_bodies;
```

Here is a link to [another Q&A with an example of working with flexible array members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19293671/335858).

Comment: That's Exactly what I was trying to do! This is a great solution. Thanks very much!