# How can I declare a structure of an unknow size?

Tags: c++

I have this structure :

```
  struct          __attribute__((packed)) BabelPacket
  {
    unsigned      senderId;
    unsigned      dataLength;
    unsigned char data[0];
  };
```

And to declare it I do :

```
  BabelPacket *packet = reinterpret_cast<BabelPacket *>(new char[sizeof(BabelPacket) + 5]);
  packet->senderId = 1;
  packet->data = "kappa";
  packet->dataLength = 5;
```

But when I compile I have this error :

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char [6]’ to ‘unsigned char [0]’
   packet->data = "kappa";

            ^
```

Have you an idea how I can do that ? 
And I need to send this structure through a socket, to get the object back in my server, so I can use only C types.

Comment: You can't in standard C++.

Comment: PD: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688471/variable-sized-struct-c Looking for a better one though.

Comment: This works in C ([like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19293671/335858)) but not in C++.

Comment: You could use pointer there and allocate the string separately.

Comment: C++ does not support array assignment. You cannot set an array equal to anything. So `packet->data = "kappa";` makes no sense under the rules of C or C++.

Comment: What the hell!!! what's the intention in writting `reinterpret_cast<BabelPacket *>(new char [sizeof(BabelPacket)])` ????

Comment: @LuisColorado I need to allocate more memory than the size of the structure, because I use a little hack that allows to have an unknown size array at the end of my structure.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov, then you lead to undefined behaviour, as new is going to call the `char[]` constructor (it doesn't exist but it should call the one for the object type you use in `new`) instead of the one you could define for your `struct`.   And no way to call it after.  The best approach is to define two structs, one with the hack and other without it (one can be a subclass of the other, so you don't need to reimplement things) and call `new` with the proper argument.  Don't think like in C when you are programming C++.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are willing/allowed to change the `unsigned char` to a regular `char`, you can use `strcpy`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct          __attribute__((packed)) BabelPacket
{
  unsigned      senderId;
  unsigned      dataLength;
  char data[0]; // I changed this to char in order to use strcpy
};

int main(){
  BabelPacket *packet = reinterpret_cast<BabelPacket *>(new char[sizeof(BabelPacket) + 5]);
  packet->senderId = 1;
  // Copy the string. Add NULL character at the end of 
  // the string to indicate its end
  strcpy(packet->data, "kappa\0"); 
  packet->dataLength = 5;

  // Verify that the string is copied properly
  for (int i=0;i<packet->dataLength;++i){
    std::cout<<packet->data[i];
  }
  std::cout<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Note that this will only work if `data` is at the end of the `struct`, otherwise there is no contiguous memory to allocate `data`. If I swap the order of the elements to:

```
struct          __attribute__((packed)) BabelPacket
{
  unsigned      senderId;
  char data[0]; // I changed this to char in order to use strcpy
  unsigned      dataLength;
};
```

the output of the code above (instead of "kappa"), would be "a".

A more reliable way if you are determined to use C-arrays would be to assume a maximum number of elements and preallocate the array, i.e.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS 5 // Many ways to do this, I defined the macro for the purposes of this example

struct          __attribute__((packed)) BabelPacket
{
  unsigned      senderId;
  // I changed this to char in order to use strcpy. Allocate the
  // max number + 1 element for the termination string
  char data[MAX_NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS+1]; 
  unsigned      dataLength;
};

int main(){
  BabelPacket *packet = reinterpret_cast<BabelPacket *>(new char[sizeof(BabelPacket) + 5]);
  packet->senderId = 1;
  packet->dataLength = 5;
  if (dataLength>MAX_NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS){
    std::cout<<"String greater than the maximum number of characters"<<std::endl;
  }
  // Copy the string. Add NULL character at the end of 
  // the string to indicate its end
  strcpy(packet->data, "kappa\0");  

  // Verify that the string is copied properly
  for (int i=0;i<packet->dataLength;++i){
    std::cout<<packet->data[i];
  }
  std::cout<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This code produces the correct output, and protects you against violations. As you can see, it can get messy pretty quickly, which is why I would recommend to use `std::vector` for this. The `dataLength` may then be retrieved automatically as the size of the vector, and you are always protected against overflows.

Comment: `char data[0];` That isn't allowed in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza I use g++ 5.4 and that is working fine.

Comment: Likewise, it works fine with clang 3.8 for me as well.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov That doesn't mean it is standard C++.

Comment: You should explain that allocation is hacked in a way to append free room at the end of the struct, and the trick will fail if the array isn't the last field. And you forgot to allocate an extra byte for the string terminator.

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot use a std::vector because I send this structure through a socket so I must C types.

Comment: You could use the pointer to the first element in the structure, and use the vector in the rest of the code to make sure memory is managed properly no?

Answer (score 3):

If this was a C program, the error you get is because you try to assign to an array, which is not possible. You can only *copy* to an array:

```
memcpy(packet->data, "kappa", 5);
```

Also note that if you want the data to be a C string, you need to allocate an extra character for the string terminator `'\0'`. Then you can use `strcpy` instead of `memcpy` above. Or `strncpy` to copy at most a specific amount of characters, but then you might need to manually terminate the string.

However, this should not work in C++ at all, unless your compiler have it as an extension.

Comment: Better provide a safer alternative to `strcpy`.

Comment: I think you mean `memcpy(packet->data, "kappa", 5);`

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a literal string that way. You'll need to allocate additional memory for the string, then copy to the data pointer.

```
struct A {
    size_t datasize;
    char data[0]; // flexible member must appear last.
};

A* create_A(const char* str)
{
    size_t datasize = strlen(str) + 1; // null terminated (?)
    A* p = reinterpret_cast<A*>(new char[sizeof(A) + datasize]);
    memcpy(p->data, str, datasize);
    p->datasize = datasize;
    return p;
}

A* p = create_A("data string");
```

This solution is only applicable in environments supporting zero-length or flexible arrays. In fact, a better solution may be to write the sockets code in C and export that interface for use in C++.

Comment: `char data[0];` That isn't allowed in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza  Considering he is using attributes, it's safe to assume he's using GCC which supports it as an extension.

Comment: That would depend on compiler flags.

Comment: Nobody is stopping you from writing a complete, precise answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza That's funny, since this is the only correct answer. The accepted answer only allocates 5 bytes, then uses strcpy which copies 6 bytes. The other answer has the operands out of order for memcpy. Actually I'm missing a comma and a semicolon. So much for precision.