# Store allocated struct (using the "struct hack") in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct, tcp, malloc

In our assignment, we have to build our own TCP handler (framework is provided). I am now at that point where I have to collect all TCP segments and store them into a vector so I can reassemble the stream after the last segment has been received, and forward it to the next layer (e.g. HTTP).
For that purpose we have to implement `void handle_packet()`. In our framework there are several structs and classes that should "help" us.

This is what I have come up so far:

**tcp.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <netinet/tcp.h> // struct tcphdr

using Header = struct tcphdr;

struct Segment {

    const Header * hdr;
    uint8_t payload[];
};

struct Stream {

  std::vector<Segment> segments;

  void add_segment(Segment new_segment);

};

void Stream::add_segment(Segment new_segment) {

    segments.push_back(new_segment);

    // testing: print all sequence numbers of each segment
    for(size_t i = 0; i < segments.size(); i++)
        std::cout << ntohl(segments[i].hdr->seq) << std::endl;
}

class Protocol {
private:
  Stream streams;

public:
  void handle_packet(const Header* tcp_segment_hdr, uint8_t* tcp_payload, size_t tcp_payload_len);
};
```

**tcp.cpp**

```
#include "tcp.h"

void handle_packet(const Header* tcp_segment_hdr, uint8_t* tcp_payload, size_t tcp_payload_len) {

    // "struct hack" to copy content 
    Segment* segment = reinterpret_cast<Segment *>(malloc(sizeof(struct Segment) + buffer_len * sizeof(uint8_t)) );

    // store the header
    segment->hdr = tcp_segment_hdr; // add the header

    // store the payload
    for(size_t i = 0; i < tcp_payload_len; i++)
        segment->payload[i] = tcp_payload[i];

    streams.add_segment(*segment);

    free(segment);
}
```

I am copying the header and the payload using the "struct hack" into a `Segment *` struct (this was the only working way I have come up with). After that I store the new segment into `streams` (member of class `Protocol`) member variable `vector<Segments>`. Then I free the memory.

After that I wanted to see if everything is stored in `segments` (for test purposes I tried to print each sequence number of a segment) - and it's not.. 
However, the size is still correct.

I guess this is because I `free'd` the struct in `handle_packet()` afterwards and this also effects my entry in `std::vector<Segment>segments`.. But how can I achieve that the entries are still in there without any memory leaks? I googled but did not find a satisyfing solution how I can solve my problem.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

**Edit**: I am also getting the following error in AddressSanitizer:

```
==22658==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 
0x7fff5288b66c at pc 0x559511b2f7bc bp 0x7fff5288b2b0 sp 0x7fff5288b2a0
WRITE of size 1 at 0x7fff5288b66c thread T0
```

In IPv4 we had the following struct:

```
struct Fragment : public std::vector<uint8_t> {
  using std::vector<uint8_t>::vector;
  const Header *getHeader() { return (const Header *)data(); }
};
```

But I did not do that part since I couldn't figure out how to "fill up" the values and add an entry. Any ideas how I can adopt `struct Fragment` to `struct Segment` and fill/add (persistent) values?

**Edit 2:** As a temporary result, I have given the payload a fixed size (1500) and remove the "struct hack" and edited it back to a simple `Segment segment`.

**Edit 3:** Ok it still doesn't work even with a fixed size..

**Edit 4:** I have found a working solution! However, I will describe my solution on saturday (after deadline) to avoid plagiarism.

Comment: Do note that `uint8_t payload[];` is **not** standard C++ and your code is **not** portable.

Comment: Is there any other standard C++ way? If yes could you provide an example? I just wanted to use the structs since they are already there.

Comment: The struct hack was the only working way?? What about `Segment segment;`? done deal. The issue is not copying the `Segment`, the issue is that you are only doing shallow copies of the data when pushing them into the vector in `Stream`.

Comment: @s.r. The C++ way to do it would be to have a `std::vector<uint8_t>` as the type for `payload`.  Doing that though requires more serialization though because you need to transmit its size so the receiver can allocate the correct amount of space before it copies the buffer into the vector.  Another thing would be to hard code a size in for `payload` but that limits you and can waste space.

Comment: @super you are right, I don't know why I didn't tried a simple `Segment segment`, but after that the problem with the "lost data" still exists.

Comment: `std::vector` needs everything in it to be of fixed size. The entire point of flexible array members is they are NOT a fixed size.

Comment: @user4581301 so what I am trying to achieve is illegal (storing a flexible array into a vector)? What would be a valid way?

Comment: Closest you'll get in C++ (without wandering off into the land of weird) is what @NathanOliver pitched above. No entirely contiguous data structure can do this. Even in C if you tried this with an array it would fail. You'd need a linked structure.

Comment: @s.r.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290293/struct-hack-equivalent-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised, here is my solution. I took the following struct definition:

```
/**
* Container for a segment of a TCP stream.
*/
struct Segment : public std::vector<uint8_t> {
    using std::vector<uint8_t>::vector; 
};
```

To copy the `segment` data into the struct I did:

```
Segment segment;

// fill the segment with the data
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < buffer_len; i++)
  segment.push_back(buffer[i]);
```

And to access the data you can use the defined `data()` member from `std::vector` (from which the struct inherits). I also had another `struct Stream`with a member called `Segment allSegments` where every `segment` was added (all segments in total). The resulting access looked like this:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < allSegments.size(); i++)
{
  for(unsigned int j = 0; j < allSegments[i].size(); j++)
    printf( "%x",allSegments[i].data()[j] );
}
```

I didn't know that you can inherit `std::vector`. The `struct Segment` was pre-defined by our study assistents and not implemented by myself. At first I didn't get how you can access the data and wanted to implement a different way - that was why I did come up with the struct hack.